# ANGULAR CLI issue

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

I created a project following all the instructions in the Angular CLI website, but when I try to build the project it gave an error like this:

[image: this]

Same project I build using `npm start` command after `npm install`

- Please advise whether this a good approach or not
- If I want to use CLI how can I fix it?
- Is installing a node module inside the project good or bad?

Comment: You should install cli globally. `npm install -g @angular/cli` ... then create the project.

Comment: Thanks @Ludwig solution worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per error message your using older version try below commands

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

angular-cli has been depreciated you just have to reinstall @angular/cli

```
1- npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
2- npm install @angular/cli --save-dev
```

to use it globally install

```
1- npm install @angular/cli -g
```

Also if you are considering Angular Ahead-of-Time, install

```
npm install --save-dev @ngtools/webpack
```

Answer (score 0):

Because angular commands has been changed. Just type
: npm install -g @angular/cli
And then it'll download/install it in your angularjs folder.

## Set the cmd path to your AJS2 folder to make it working. :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. reinstalled nodejs. This fixed the issue